# Get a value from a shortcode for another function

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I use a shortcode to get the value and try to use it to calculate the percentage

```
$target_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'target_price', true );
$now_price = do_shortcode ( '[stock_market_widget type="inline" template="generic" assets="'. $stock = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'stock', true ) .'" markup="{price}" api="yf"]' );
$procent = ((int)$target_price - (int)$now_price) * 100 / (int)$now_price ;

echo $now_price;
echo $target_price;
echo $procent;
```

But the shortcode doesn't return a value, it returns this code
[image]

How do I get the value from the shortcode that is in "smw-field-value"?
Thanks

Comment: Please show the full code, so that people can offer the correct advice.

Comment: The stock_market_widget shortcode is obviously set up to return you HTML, which is normal for a shortcode. You'll either have to parse the value out of that - which you can probably do with normal string operations and html_entity_decode or similar once you've got the value part from the tags, or look at the code that implements stock_market_widget to find out how it's getting the value as a value and if there are any alternative ways of getting the value out of the code rather than as HTML.